# Check if the string is palindrome

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

The following code runs correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

bool is_palindrom(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string temp(str);
    std::transform(temp.begin(), temp.end(), temp.begin(), ::tolower);
    return temp == std::string(temp.rbegin(), temp.rend());
}

int main()
{
    std::string str{ "KArak" };
    std::cout << is_palindrom(str) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Can I do this better? The constraint is to keep the declaration of the function the same and only change the implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**To the readers:** <strike>I had to use `::tolower` because the `std::` version was causing compiler errors. I'm investigating this right now.</strike> The issue stems from `std::tolower` being overloaded. What is funny is that it is in header `<locale>`, which means that the standard library implementation includes it in some way. Rakete1111 proposed lambda version, which works great.

Yes.

**Use more standard library:**

The `std::string` provides reverse iterators, so there is no need to do any copy at all. In fact, it is possible to it with indices, but it won't look that pretty:

```
    return std::equal(str.cbegin(), str.cbegin() + str.size() / 2, str.crbegin(), 
                      [](unsigned char lhs, unsigned char rhs) {
                          return std::tolower(lhs) == std::tolower(rhs);
                      });
```

The actual version was different, thanks to Rakete1111 for a new version. There is a note in the comments from Loki and Jerry: it seems like using functions in `<cctype>` are dangerous and will result in undefined behavior unless the input is cast into `unsigned char` first.

It is also possible to refactor the ugly `+ str.size() / 2` into reusable function:

```
#include <iterator>

//some namespace
template <typename Container>
constexpr auto mid(const Container& container)
{
    auto half_distance = std::distance(std::begin(container), 
                                       std::end(container)) / 2;
    return std::next(container.begin(), half_distance);
}
```

Then it transforms into:

```
bool is_palindrome(const std::string& str) {
    return std::equal(str.cbegin(), mid(str), str.crbegin(), 
                      [](unsigned char lhs, unsigned char rhs) {
                          return std::tolower(lhs) == std::tolower(rhs);
                      });
}
```

**Other things that could be done better:**

- Avoid `std::endl`. It can cause big performance issues.
- There is a typo in the word palindrome.
- `std::boolalpha` could be used to provide more user friendly output.
- more unit tests.
- It seems like the code is missing `<cctype>` header as well.
- putting everything into a namespace. Absence of it will force users to do unqualified call, which is prone to ADL, which is sometimes very evil.

**Put together:**

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <iterator>

//some namespace
template <typename Container>
constexpr auto mid(const Container& container)
{
    auto half_distance = std::distance(std::begin(container), 
                                       std::end(container)) / 2;
    return std::next(container.begin(), half_distance);
}

bool is_palindrome(const std::string& str) {
    return std::equal(str.cbegin(), mid(str), str.crbegin(), 
                      [](unsigned char lhs, unsigned char rhs) {
                          return std::tolower(lhs) == std::tolower(rhs);
                      });
}

int main()
{
    std::string str{ "KArak" };
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "is \"KArak\" palindrome? " << is_palindrome(str) << '\n';
    std::cout << "is \"fuf\" palindrome? " << is_palindrome("fuf") << '\n';
    std::cout << "is empty string palindrome? " << is_palindrome("") << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UDJEzPi1wsqkp9Ha).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61818/discussion-between-incomputable-and-21koizyd).

Comment: Please keep this in chat now (the room above).