# Tests for palindromes in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, interview-questions, palindrome, iteration

A question I've been asked on interactive phone screens is to code a test to determine whether a string is
a palindrome or not. I am providing two examples here: one in C and one in C++. They both work and they both compile
without errors or warnings. I believe my C example is good, with the possible exception of variable names
(some of you may not like the `register char* declarations`, but they are valid in C).

My goal was an \$O(n)\$ solution with out reversing the string.

My question is about the C++ version, and I miss using iterators. Is there a way to make this more C++ like?

I can think in C; I can't necessarily think in C++.

**Palindrome checker in C**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool palindromeChecker(char *possiblePalindrome)
{
    bool isPalindrome = true;
    size_t length = strlen(possiblePalindrome);

    if (length < 3)
    {
        isPalindrome = false;
    }
    else
    {
        register char *leftSide = possiblePalindrome;
        register char *rightSide = &possiblePalindrome[length-1];

        while ((leftSide < rightSide) && isPalindrome)
        {
            if (*leftSide != *rightSide)
            {
                isPalindrome = false;
            }
            leftSide++;
            --rightSide;
        }
    }

    return isPalindrome;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char testString[BUFSIZ];
    bool iSPalendrome;

    printf("Enter a test string to be checked for if it is a palindrome\n");
    scanf("%s", testString);
    iSPalendrome = palindromeChecker(testString);
    printf("The test string %s is %s a palindrome\n", testString, (iSPalendrome? "" : "Not"));

}
```

**Palindrome checker in C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool IsPalindrome(std::string PossiblePalindrome)
{
    bool Palidrime = true;

    if (PossiblePalindrome.size() < 3)
    {
        Palidrime = false;
    }
    else
    {
        std::string::iterator leftSide = PossiblePalindrome.begin();
        std::string::iterator rightSide = PossiblePalindrome.end();
        rightSide--; // end is past the end of the possible palindrome so decrement to point to a character.

        while ((leftSide < rightSide) && Palidrime)
        {
            if (*leftSide != *rightSide)
            {
                Palidrime = false;
            }
            leftSide++;
            rightSide--;
        }
    }

    return Palidrime;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::string PossiblePalindrome;
    std::cout << "Enter a string to test to see if it is a palindrome.\n";
    std::cin >> PossiblePalindrome;

    std::cout << "The string " << PossiblePalindrome;
    if (IsPalindrome(PossiblePalindrome))
    {
        std::cout << " is";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << " is not";
    }
    std::cout << " a palindrome" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Since you’ve posted the C code: `register` might be *valid* C but that’s pretty irrelevant on a *Code Review* site. Is it good C? No: it’s pretty much obsolete. In fact, *if* the compiler honours it at all it’s more likely than not to screw with the compiler’s own, much superior optimisation logic. Don’t use `register`. *Definitely* not here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It _does_ tell the compiler that you're never going to dereference the variable... not that it doesn't know that in 80% of cases.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 My point exactly. The compile can figure this out on its own just fine.

Comment: @pacmaninbw In the C++ code you have a variable called `Palidrime`. Is that a typo or am I just unaware of the word?

Comment: @Maybe_Factor: And in the C code, a variable named `Palendrome`. I think typos...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are some things to be said about your C version as well, but since you explicitly asked about the C++ version (and also because my C-knowledge is not that great), I will leave those for somebody else to comment on.

## General Hints and Tips

1. You are passing `possiblePalindrome` by value where a pass by `const&` would be much more appropriate since you don't modify the string.
2. Prefer early return over putting your whole code inside an if-else construct. To my mind, at least,

   ```
   if (PossiblePalindrome.size() < 3)
   {
       Palidrime = false;
   }
   else //...
   ```

   should rather be

   ```
   if (PossiblePalindrome.size() < 3)
   {
       return false;
   } //no else
   ```

   This helps eliminate redundant layers of indentation and makes the code more readable.
3. Since you don't write anything to the argument string, you should use `std::string::const_iterator` to iterate it (in addition to making the parameter `const`, see point 1).
4. Please, don't use `std::endl`. It's horrible. Why? Because it does not do what its name advises and is pretty much redundant. `std::endl` *does* write an end-of-line character, but it also flushes the underlying buffer, which is seldom what you want (and if you really need that functionality, you should use `std::flush`).

## Making your Code more C++-y

As you remarked yourself, your current code is not very much C++-like, but we're going to change that by making good use of the standard library. As you know, checking whether a string is a palindrome is equal to checking the to halves of the string for equality, only that the latter half is traversed in reverse order. Luckily for us, checking ranges of elements for equality is one of the things that are needed quite frequently by a lot of people, so C++ offers the very useful `std::equal`.

`std::equal`, in its most basic form, takes three iterators: one to the beginning of a range of elements, one to its end, and another one that points to the beginning of the range the elements should be compared with. The only problem here is that we actually need our second range to be iterated in reverse. Again, the STL comes to our rescue. There is `std::reverse_iterator`, which, who would have guessed, allows iterating in reverse order, and also `rbegin`, which is a member function of `std::string` that returns a reverse iterator from the end of the string.

Combining these, we get

```
bool is_palindrome(std::string const& s) {

    if (s.size() < 3) {
        return false;
    }

    return std::equal(s.begin(), s.end(), s.rbegin());
}
```

However, as you might have already noticed, we're wasting something here. In particular, we iterate through the whole string although we actually only need to check up to the middle. Thus, we adapt our code accordingly:

```
bool is_palindrome(std::string const& s) {

    if (s.size() < 3) {
        return false;
    }

    auto end_it = s.begin();
    std::advance(end_it, std::distance(end_it, s.end()) / 2);

    return std::equal(s.begin(), end_it, s.rbegin());
}
```

(Note that you don't actually need `std::advance` here, but I prefer to use it as a good practice for the case that I'm writing code where I don't deal with random access iterators.)

This is the best solution I could come up with. If you have any improvements, be free to beat me to it.

Comment: I'd use std::next instead of std::advance to avoid creating variable and then changing it's value

Comment: @RiaD Inlining the variable here would be a little too much for one line, I think. I'd say either `std::next` or `std::advance` is fine.

Comment: I don't mean inline it but I think it's fine too), but `auto end_it = std::next(end_it, std::distance(end_it, s.end()) / 2);` it's easier to reason about things that don't change.

Comment: But I'd agree that it's not super important

Comment: I assume you meant `auto end_it = std::next(s.begin(), std::distance(s.begin(), s.end()) / 2);`, @RiaD? And while we're at it, I'd prefer to rename it to, say, `middle_it`. But I do agree that the line `auto end_it = s.begin();` just looks wrong, and forces one to look twice to figure out that it's *not* a bug in the context where it's used. Better IMO to just immediately set the iterator to the value it's actually going to have.

Answer (score 22):

- A special case `length < 3` seems like a bug. A string `aa` *is* a palindrome, and one could successfully argue that a single-letter string is also a palindrome.
- A boolean `isPalindrome` is redundant, and forces the code to test the effectively same condition twice. An early return is perfectly fine here.
- A traditional idiomatic (and arguably more performant) way to iterate forward is `*first++`. Similarly, an idiom for iterating backwards is `*--last` (that also avoids subtracting 1 beforehand):

  ```
      last = possiblePalindrome.end();
      while (first < last) {
          if (*first++ != *--last) {
              return false;
          }
      }
      return true;
  ```
- The naming is very inconsistent. I don't see the reason to spell `palindrome` in 3 different ways. A capitalization in `iSPalendrome` is also strange.

Comment: Shouldn't backwards be `*last--`?

Comment: @incomputable No. Just don't decrement it beforehand. See edit.

Comment: *arguably more performant* => really? I see no reason to obfuscate the code with piling as many operations as possible on a single line.

Answer (score 13):

I've seen a lot of answers here over-generalizing. You're dealing with a `std::string`, so you can just do:

```
bool IsPalindrome(const std::string& s) {
    return std::equal(s.begin(), s.begin() + s.size() / 2, s.rbegin());
}
```

You don't need anything fancy to find the midpoint. Just add the size/2. As others have mentioned, take the string by `const std::string&`

Comment: So @BenSteffan's answer?  The over-generalizing critique of other answers probably could have just been a comment.

Comment: @Snowhawk At least 3 answers here got that midpoint using `std::next`, `std::distance`, function templates, or all of the above. Could've just added. Nothing wrong with those approaches for generic code, but prefer the simplest method.

Comment: Prefer to use the standalone functions `std::begin(c)` rather than `c.begin()` etc... . This makes your code easier to generalize.

Comment: @LokiAstari there's some contention over that advice. Personally, I'm with the camp that says use the free functions when you need to use them generically (such as when the container is a template type), otherwise use the member functions. I don't believe in over-generalizing in C++ as it can often be more complicated more verbose code.

Comment: @David: I would love to read any articles that describe this contention in the community if you have any links.

Comment: @LokiAstari, I believe Herb Sutter is on the other camp. There was a proposal authored by him, but I believe it was not accepted.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Actually, if you go the free function route, it should really be `using std::begin; begin(c)`, so that if a type defines a free-standing `begin` rather than a member function `begin` it's also picked up. And that *really* verbose, compared to `c.begin()`. I don't see the point of using free-standing `begin`/`end` when unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

### Code Review

- Relatively low level

  Usually there is a standard library algorithms for most of uses
- Pass by value

  With `std::move()` it would be reasonable, but passing by lvalue will incur a redundant copy.
- Undocumented/unclear assumptions

  One of them is that only palindromes of length 3 and higher can be palindromes.
- Verbose control flow

  One could immediately return after seeing that it is not palindrome.

---

I've actually [answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/168706/93301) one of these before.  I wouldn't say it is canonical though. Here is what I've got:

```
template <typename Container>
constexpr auto middle(const Container& container)
{
    auto half_distance = std::distance(std::begin(container), 
                                       std::end(container)) / 2;
    return std::next(container.begin(), half_distance);
}

bool is_palindrome(const std::string& str) {
    return std::equal(str.cbegin(), middle(str), str.crbegin());
}
```

### Advantages

- Iterators

  This will allow easy transition to some other type
- Standard algorithms

  No reinvention of a wheel, tested and updated by people who (usually) know what they're doing. Very condensed, yet clean code.

---

As people in the comments suggested, one can easily generalize that:

```
template <typename Container>
constexpr auto middle(const Container& container)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    auto half_distance = std::distance(begin(container), 
                                       end(container)) / 2;
    return std::next(begin(container), half_distance);
}

template <typename Container>
bool is_palindrome(const Container& container) {
    using std::cbegin;
    using std::crbegin;
    return std::equal(cbegin(container), middle(container), 
                      crbegin(container));
}
```

Comment: OP's code and your code are not functionally equivalent. In particular, OP's code is case sensitive whereas yours is not.

Comment: @BenSteffan, thanks for noticing. I kind of skipped the problem definition, a really bad habit.

Comment: Prefer using `std::begin(str)` and similar functions over calling `str.cbegin()` directly (after all, you already do it in `middle`). Also, that way, `is_palindrome` could easily be generalized to check any container whether it is equal to its reversal. `template<typename Container> bool is_palindrome(const Container& cont) { return std::equal(std::begin(cont), middle(cont), std::rbegin(cont)); }`

Comment: @Snowhawk, thanks. This might as well be canonical now.

Comment: This is a great solution (+1) but it’s not a code review.

Comment: @Incomputable It's definitely a review now.

Comment: @pacmaninbw, thanks for waiting. I thought I could just link similar post and get away with it :)

Comment: @BenSteffan personally, I would go for case insensitive matching. _Racecar_ is a palindrome, even if the first and last characters have different code-points.  Of course if the specification is for case sensitive, then that's what we do, unless it is agreed that the specification is incorrect and can be changed.

Answer (score 5):

Using the standard functions it becomes relatively simple (a one liner).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::string data = "panap";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << std::equal(std::begin(data),
                            std::begin(data) + (std::size(data) / 2), 
                            std::rbegin(data))
              << "\n";
}
```

Lets compare this to yours:

#### Pass by const reference to avoid a copy.

```
bool IsPalindrome(std::string PossiblePalindrome)
```

Here you are passing the string by value. This basically causes the string to be copied (an O(n) operation).

#### Not sure this is true.

```
    if (PossiblePalindrome.size() < 3)
    {
        Palidrime = false;
    }
```

Unless they gave you special instructions. A zero and one length string is a palindrome.

#### Use auto when you can

```
        std::string::iterator leftSide = PossiblePalindrome.begin();
        std::string::iterator rightSide = PossiblePalindrome.end();
```

Sure you can go full out and specify the types. But in modern C++ we usually like the compiler to deduce the types (especially if the exact type is not important: for iterators the exact type is not important, just the fact that it is in the group of types that implement an iterator).

```
        auto leftSide = PossiblePalindrome.begin();
        auto rightSide = PossiblePalindrome.end();
```

#### Prefer to use pre-increment.

It makes very little difference in this context (so I am not bashing you for this exact usage). But it does make a tiny difference and if used in the wrong place can cause a difference.

So since the pre-increment achieves the same result and is optimal prefer to use this one as in the long run it will pay off.

```
        rightSide--;
```

#### Why not use a break in the loop?

```
        while ((leftSide < rightSide) && Palidrime)
        {
            if (*leftSide != *rightSide)
            {
                Palidrime = false;
                // I would just have put a break here.
                // this simplifies the loop test above.
            }
            leftSide++;
            rightSide--;
        }
```

If you simplify the loop it becomes:

```
        for (;(leftSide < rightSide); ++leftSide, --rightSide)
        {
            if (*leftSide != *rightSide)
            {
                Palidrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
```

#### Be consistent with braces.

You normally line your braces up on the same horizontal. But here you place it on the end of the line:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
```

Both are fine. **BUT** for neat code you should be consistent in your usage.

Notice that the `operator>>` only reads a single space separated word.

```
    std::cin >> PossiblePalindrome;
```

There are a lot of interesting palindromes that use spaces (that are ignored).

```
    A man a plan a canal Panama
```

If you ignore space and capitalization the above is an palindrome. You could have used `std::getline()` to read a line of text from the user.

#### Use ternary operator (judicially)

```
    if (IsPalindrome(PossiblePalindrome))
    {
        std::cout << " is";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << " is not";
    }
    std::cout << " a palindrome" << std::endl;
```

This case can be simplified using the ternary operator?

```
    std::cout << "The string "
              << PossiblePalindrome
              << " is"
              << (!IsPalindrome(PossiblePalindrome) ? " not":"")
              << " a palindrome" << "\n";
```

#### Prefer `'\n'` over `std::endl`

The only difference here is a flush of the buffer.
Manually flushing the buffer is actually the major cause of slow down in C++ i/o based code. The system libraries are practically optimal in the timing for flush and any attempt by you will just usually screw things up.

So the general case start with `'\n'` then test to see if `std::endl` improves (it generally will not).

Comment: Palidrime? In the future it might be worth copy/pasting from the question directly...

Comment: @Toby I'm not sure how that matters? It's spelled `isPalindrome` in the question, not `Palidrime`. (And if the question has been edited, which I can't easily tell on mobile, then it should be rolled back and the asker informed that code in questions shouldn't be changed after you get an answer)

Answer (score 4):

Not a complete critique of your code, but

- The condition on the length is wrong. "A" is a palindrome, as is "BB". It's an open question whether "" is a palindrome though.
- No need to copy the string being tested, use a const ref. You're not changing it.

Answer (score 4):

Before coding, did you go over the requirements with the interviewer?  Are strings limited to just words?  What about sentences/phrases? Any adjustments for capital letters, punctuation, word dividers? Consider that the phrases *A man, a plan, a canal, Panama!", "Was it a car or a cat I saw?", or "No 'x' in Nixon" are considered palindromic phrases.

Also, why do you ignore strings of length 1 and 2?  Document the reasoning.

---

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
```

Omit the parameters of `main` if you do not intend on utilising command-line arguments.

---

```
    std::cin >> PossiblePalindrome;
```

When reading from a stream, check to make sure the read was successful.

---

Simplify your logic.

```
    std::cout << "The string " << PossiblePalindrome << " is ";
    if (!IsPalindrome(PossiblePalindrome))
    {
        std::cout << "not ";
    }
    std::cout << "a palindrome.\n";
```

---

Split your library code from your test code.

Instead of letting a user pump in data, grab a testing framework and write actual tests. See [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2), [GoogleTest](https://github.com/google/googletest), or [Boost.Test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/test/doc/html/index.html).  Here is a Catch2 example:

```
#include "palindrome.hpp"

#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp"

TEST_CASE( "Empty String", "[empty]" ) {
    REQUIRE( IsPalindrome("") );
}

TEST_CASE( "Short Strings", "[short]" ) {
    REQUIRE( IsPalindrome("ANNA") );
    /* ... */
}

TEST_CASE( "Long Strings", "[long]" ) {
    REQUIRE( IsPalindrome("Degas, are we not drawn onward, no? In union, drawn onward to new eras aged?") );
    /* ... */
}

TEST_CASE( "Absurdly Long Strings", "[absurdly-long]" ) {
    REQUIRE( IsPalindrome("Dennis, Nell, Edna, Leon, Nedra, Anita, Rolf, Nora, Alice, Carol, Leo, Jane, Reed, Dena, Dale, Basil, Rae, Penny, Lana, Dave, Denny, Lena, Ida, Bernadette, Ben, Ray, Lila, Nina, Jo, Ira, Mara, Sara, Mario, Jan, Ina, Lily, Arne, Bette, Dan, Reba, Diane, Lynn, Ed, Eva, Dana, Lynne, Pearl, Isabel, Ada, Ned, Dee, Rena, Joel, Lora, Cecil, Aaron, Flora, Tina, Arden, Noel, and Ellen sinned.") );
    /* ... */
}
```

See [PalindromeList](http://www.palindromelist.net/) for palindromes to test with.  Make sure you also check non-palindromes.

---

```
bool IsPalindrome(std::string PossiblePalindrome)
```

For input parameters that aren't modified, only pass cheaply-copied types (2-3 Bytes) by value.  Pass anything else by reference to `const`.  There are exceptions (sink or copy required params).

---

```
bool Palidrime = true;
```

Be consistent with your spelling.

Rather than tracking the state, simplify the logic and just return as soon as you encounter a bad character.

Prefer the member `cbegin()`/`cend()` to make it clear to readers that the elements of the range are immutable.

```
    if (PossiblePalindrome.size() < 3)
    {
         return false;
    }

    auto leftSide = PossiblePalindrome.cbegin();
    auto rightSide = PossiblePalindrome.cend();
```

---

```
    while ((leftSide < rightSide) && Palidrime)
    {
        if (*leftSide != *rightSide)
        {
            Palidrime = false;
        }
        leftSide++;
        rightSide--;
    }
```

This looks to be a candidate to be a standalone function.  As others have pointed out, it's `std::equal` with a range and its corresponding `std::reverse_iterator`.

Comment: A lot of good points. I don't remember the exact requirement, I only thought of single words when I was asked the question. I should have asked that specific question.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the flag variables, there is nothing wrong with using a `return` statement as soon as you know the result.

This is how I would implement it in C, continually compare the start and end characters until they are different or they meet in the middle.

```
bool isPalindrome(const char* word)
{
    for (const char *b = word, *e = (word + strlen(word) - 1); b < e; ++b, --e)
    {
        if (*b != *e) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

In C++ using the same algorithm

```
bool isPalindrome(const std::string &word)
{
    for (auto b = word.cbegin(), e = word.cend() - 1; b < e; ++b, --e)
    {
        if (*b != *e) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Take care with inputs and outputs

Spot the problem here:

```
char testString[BUFSIZ];
scanf("%s", testString);
```

Although `testString` only has enough space to hold `BUFSIZ` characters (including the string terminator), we read an *unbounded* string from standard input.  And never test the result of `scanf`, so we don't know whether any characters were even read.

There's also no checking of the result of `printf()` - that's arguably not a problem here, but in an interview question, I'd expect to see a comment explaining that you have consciously chosen to skip the check that you would normally put in your production code.

The buffer overrun isn't a problem in the C++ version (as a `std::string` will expand as necessary), but there is a missing check of `cin.good()` after reading from it.  The idiomatic form is something like

```
if (std::cin >> PossiblePalindrome) {
    // ...
} else {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to read input");
}
```

## Write for localisation

Assembling strings like this can harm the localisability of your messages:

```
printf("The test string %s is %s a palindrome\n", testString, (iSPalendrome? "" : "Not"));
```

Not all languages can negate a sentence with a single change to one part like this, so if your program were to be internationalized and ship with message catalogs for each language, this statement would probably need to be re-written.  Perhaps something like the following would be better:

```
printf(iSPalindrome
         ? "The test string %s is a palindrome\n"
         : "The test string %s is not a palindrome\n",
       testString);
```

But I'd lean towards an `if`/`else` so that the compiler can still check that the arguments agree with the format string.

The C++ exhibits a similar problem.  Additionally, the C version will output a doubled space ("`is  a`") for the negative case.  That could have been avoided by moving one of the spaces into the `"Not"` - but don't compose strings like that anyway.

Comment: Yes the C version added the space, I changed it in the C++ version. It's funny, after all the times I beat on people to check input for errors, I forgot it myself. I chose BUFSIZ because it's a common header macro, and it generally evaluates to 1024.

Answer (score 1):

For the C++ code I would write the following

```
template<typename biDiIt, typename compare>
bool
isPalindrome(biDiIt first, biDiIt last, compare comp)
{
  const auto dist = std::distance(first,last);
  const auto rev_last = std::make_reverse_iterator(last);
  const auto mid = std::next(first,dist/2);
  return std::equal(first, mid, rev_last, comp);
}

template<typename biDiIt>
bool
isPalindrome(biDiIt first, biDiIt last)
{
  using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<biDiIt>::value_type;
  return isPalindrome(first, last, std::equal_to<value_type>() );
}
```

This is code in the spirit of the standard template library, and it would work for any data structure equipped with bidirectional iterators.  It also can use a custom comparision function if you wanted to say, for example that all vowels are equivalent and all constanants are equivalent.

So for your function we would write

```
bool
isPalindrome(const std::string& input)
{
   return isPalindrome(std::begin(input), std::end(input));
}
```